# CloudFront atomic replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I want to host a static site via Amazon CloudFront from an S3 bucket. If I update the content of the bucket with a new version of the page, is there a way I can ensure the distribution happens in an atomic way?

What I mean is, if I have assets like `a.js` and `b.js`, that the updated version of both is served at the same time, and not e.g. the old `a.js` and new `b.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. You can request an invalidation. Takes about 15 minutes or so to complete.
2. You can give your new assets a new name. This is a bit harder to do, but in my opinion the preferable route. Since its easier to enable long expiration client side caching.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform object invalidataion, there is no gurantee that two js files will be invalidataed at the same time. There would definitely be some time when your site will behave unexpectedly.

Either you do it at a time when you expect least number of users visiting your site Or create new resources like "datasage" mentioned & then use names of these newly created resources to update all the files that reference these.